# How to pass command line argument with space in Bash scripts

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

Let's say there is one script `s1`, and I need to pass argument `$1` with value `foo bar`, with space in it. This can be done

> ./s1 "foo bar"

however, when I want to run the above command in another script (say `s2`), how should I put it? If I put it as above, `foo bar` will be interpreted as two arguments (to s1) rather than one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try quoting `$1`:

```
./s2 "$1"
```

Comment: do you mind explaining what would ``s2`` looks like? I don't need to pass argument to ``s2``, but to ``s1``.

Comment: @Richard I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Can you clarify ?

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes.

`./script 'this is a line'`

To consider variable substitutions use double quotes

`./script "this is a line"`

Answer (score -4):

How about:

```
./s1 foo\ bar
```

Would that work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did not have sufficient reputation to have the ability to make a comment on this post. I will keep this in mind next time.