# Using "mail -a" with $Sender var

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to make a bash script that will send an email and I was wondering if it's possible to type my sender as variable? 
example:

```
#!/bin/bash
SENDER="From: Test <test@test.local>"
echo "Hello" | mail -a $SENDER -s "Subject" myemail@test.local
```

Right now it will send the email with no sender name.

Comment: [How to pass command line argument with space in Bash scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11870325/608639)

Answer (score 1):

Found working answer:
Certainly your problem is caused by missing quotes.
All $variables should be in quotes, in case they contain special characters (like newlines).
Working code:

```
#!/bin/bash
SENDER="From: Test <test@test.local>"
echo "Hello" | mail -a "$SENDER" -s "Subject" myemail@test.local
```